# how to add manual magento login and registration for android webservice

Tags: php, magento, authentication

i want to add manual magento login and registration webservice for my android project. and how to do that with the help of php? i've tried these steps for login

```
    <?php
    class My_Module_Controller extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
        public function indexAction() {
    // if customer is not logged in
            if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
            {
    // get the email and load the customer by id
                $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
                $email = $login['hi@gmail.com'];
                $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                    ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()
                        ->getWebsiteId())->loadByEmail($email);
                $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();

    //If the customer exists, log them in by forwarding to loginPost
                if($customer->getId())
                {
    // just make the customer log in
                    $mysession = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
                    $mysession->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart'));
                    $mysession->setAfterAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart'));
                    $this->_forward('login','account','customer');
                }
                else
                {
    //There is no customer with that email.
                }
            }
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

and this for registration

```
    public function indexAction()
    {
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
    }
    public function loginAction()
    {
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
    // is already login redirect to account page
    return;
    }
    $result = array('success' => false);
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost())
    {
    $login_data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
    if (empty($login_data['username']) || empty($login_data['password'])) {
    $result['error'] = Mage::helper('onepagecheckout')->__('Login and password are required.');
    }
    else
    {
    try
    {
    $session->login($login_data['username'], $login_data['password']);
    $result['success'] = true;
    $result['redirect'] = Mage::getUrl('*/*/index');
    }
    catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e)
    {
    switch ($e->getCode()) {
    case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
    $message = Mage::helper('onepagecheckout')->__('Email is not confirmed. Resend confirmation email.', Mage::helper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login_data['username']));
    break;
    default:
    $message = $e->getMessage();
    }
    $result['error'] = $message;
    $session->setUsername($login_data['username']);
    }
    }
    }
    $this->_redirect('customer/account/');
    //$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
    }
```

but i am unable to do it.and how can i make it run
I took this code from net by googling it

Answer (score 0):

For login

```
$websiteId = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($store)->getWebsiteId();
        $res = array();
        $res["username"] = $username;
        $res["password"] = base64_decode($password);
        $login_status = 1; 
        try{
         $login_customer_result = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId($websiteId)->authenticate($username, base64_decode($password));
             $login_customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
             $login_customer->loadByEmail($username);             
             $res["firstname"] = $login_customer->firstname;
             $res["lastname"] = $login_customer->lastname;
             $res["id"] = $login_customer->getId(); 
             //$res["password"]
             //$res["password"]
        }
        catch( Exception $e ){
             $login_status = 0;
        }
        $res["login_status"] = $login_status;
        return $res;
```

Fir registration

```
$res = array();
        $websiteId = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($store)->getWebsiteId(); 
        $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
        $customer->website_id = $websiteId;
        $customer->setCurrentStore($store);
              //  echo 'Phase 2';
        try {
            // If new, save customer information
            $customer->firstname = $firstname;
            $customer->lastname = $lastname;
            $customer->email = $email;
            $customer->password_hash = md5(base64_decode($password));
            $res["email"] =$email;
            $res["firstname"] =$firstname;
            $res["lastname"] =$lastname;
            $res["password"] =$password;
            $res["status"] = 0;
                    $res["id"] = 0;
            $cust = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
                ->loadByEmail($email);

                    //check exists email address of users  
                    if ($cust->getId()) {
            $res["id"] = $cust->getId();
                    $res["status"] = 0;                     
            }else {
            //echo 'Phase 2.5';
             if($customer->save()){
                     $customer->sendNewAccountEmail('confirmed');
                     $this->send_Password_Mail_to_NewUser($firstname, base64_decode($password), $email);
                     $res["id"] = $customer->getId();
                 $res["status"] = 1;                               
             }
            else{
                       //echo "Already Exist";
                $exist_customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
                        $exist_customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);                        
                        $exist_customer->setCurrentStore($store);
                        $exist_customer->loadByEmail($email);                       
                        $res["id"] = $exist_customer->getId();
                        $res["status"] = 1;                

             //echo "An error occured while saving customer";
             } 
            }
                    //echo 'Phase 3';
        }

        catch(Exception $e){

                    //echo "Already Exist Exception";
                      try {
                        $exist_customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
                        $exist_customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);

                        $exist_customer->setCurrentStore($store);
                        $exist_customer->loadByEmail($email);

                        $res["id"] = $exist_customer->getId();
                        $res["status"] = 1;
                       }
                      catch(Exception $ex) {
                        $res["id"] = -1;
                        $res["status"] = 0;
                     }  
        }
        return $res;
```

Comment: hi santhosh thanks for your post as i am a new comer for magento how can i add these to my web service file.can i add between <?php ...?> like this or should i use some code. help me to find out